# CoroutineWorker class not instantiated in android

Tags: android, android-workmanager, coroutineworker

I have been trying to get coroutine worker class run in an android app I am working with. I am also trying to inject dependences to the class. See codes below

```
@HiltWorker
class BackgroundWorker@AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    val myRepository: Repository
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        val data = myRepository.getMessageList()
        val outputData = workDataOf(Constants.WORKER_OUTPUT to "data")

        return Result.success(outputData)

    }
}
```

My app module looks like below

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideConverterFactory(): GsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAPIService(retrofit: Retrofit): API = retrofit.create(API::class.java)


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRepository(api: API): Repository = RepositoryImpl(api)
}
```

My applicaion class looks like

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class NyangaSMSApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider{
    var mNetworkMonitoringUtil: NetworkMonitoringUtil? = null

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
    override fun onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
            .build()
}
```

Manifest file contains

```
    <application
        android:name=".NyangaSMSApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NyangaSMS">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">

        </provider>

    </application>
```

dependencies

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

work_version = '2.7.1'
hilt_version = '2.38.1'
```

With all this setup. I get the error while trying to run worker

```
E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.example.nyangasms.ui.main.BackgroundWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2166)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:245)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:137)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2022-06-04 16:31:19.816 433-631/com.example.nyangasms E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Could not create Worker com.example.nyangasms.ui.main.BackgroundWorker
```

Please, what could I be missing?